# Is it possible to use google.protobuffer to serialize data without prefixing the length of each data field?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

By default, unless ive done something wrong, protobuf prefixes all data fields with the length of the data that follows. for example, if i do:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MessagePayload msg = new MessagePayload()
        {
            Message = "hello"
        };

        var bytes = new byte[8];

        var output = new CodedOutputStream(bytes);

        output.WriteMessage(msg);

        Console.WriteLine(CryptoBytes.ToHexStringLower(bytes));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

it prints out:

```
07120568656c6c6f
```

but what i want is:

```
0568656c6c6f
```

is there a way to have protobuf do this somehow, without manually removing the length fields?

Comment: why use typical binary protocol to printing?

Comment: re tags: this isn't protobuf-net - that looks like the Google C# version (protobuf-net is an entirely independent implementation of the same specification)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. As described in the encoding here https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding strings must all be prefixed with their size. "A wire type of 2 (length-delimited) means that the value is a varint encoded length followed by the specified number of bytes of data. "

Answer (score 1):

The only byte that is removable there is the `07` - that isn't part of the regular protobuf specification, and the *raw protobuf output* for that message is just `120568656c6c6f`. The leading `07` is an unrelated length prefix that is presumably part of `CodedOutputStream`, but is **not** part of the regular protobuf output. You can probably avoid that by *not using `CodedOutputStream`*, but just using the other available methods perhaps on `msg`.

The `12` here means "field number: 2, type: length-delimited". That tells me that `Message` quite possibly isn't the only field defined on `MessagePayload`, so no: you can't remove that. And even if it **was** the only field on `MessagePayload`: the protobuf specification doesn't care: *every field present* gets a field header.

To be honest, if all you want is to send is a string, then: *don't use protobuf* - just use UTF-8 to encode the string, prepend the length-prefix in whatever way you choose (protobuf uses "varint"), and you're done. However, if you want to send more complex structured data, you'll need *some overheads* to allow for that. That's what the `12` is here.

For the record: there are 6 "wire types" defined in protobuf, and only one of them (wire type 2) involves a length prefix. Many fields *don't* involve a length prefix. In your example, the only length prefix *in the actual protobuf data* is the `05`, which is one of the bytes you said you *wish to keep*.

Comment: thanks for the tips. i need the initial length at the start though. there is a lot more to it than just whats shown. i need to serialize a relatively large data structures (~150 - ~600 bytes). im using protobuf because it will be used for documentation and so that others can simply copy the .proto file and implement the same, instead of having to implement the data structure themselves which can be quite tricky.

Comment: @kodty you say you need the initial length, but in the question you **removed** the initial length. You can see why I might be confused by this... but: if you remove the field headers, no protobuf library will be able to work with the data

Comment: 05 68656c6c6f -> the 07 reduced to 05 due to removing the 1205. 
it is only used to serialization, not deserialization. the serialized data is sent to an end point which isnt protobuf, so it doesnt matter if the headers are removed - its actually necessary. saying to other devs "build this .proto file, populate the data and then remove the headers" is much simpler than saying "you have to manually serialize the data in this structure" because the structures can be complex.

Comment: @kodty k, but no protobuf library is going to help you with that

Comment: well, i just wrote something to manually remove the field length headers, and its working fine.